AWS Elastic BeanStalk not deploying ebextensions file, with Spring Boot
I am using Spring Kotlin, and am trying to upload this to Elastic Beanstalk.
When I do "eb deploy", it uploads the JAR file
My settings are:
branch-defaults:
  master:
    environment: rest-api-env
environment-defaults:
  DF-server-rest-api-env:
    branch: null
    repository: null
global:
  application_name: rest-api
  default_ec2_keyname: aws-eb
  default_platform: Corretto 21 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2023
  default_region: eu-west-2
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: s_t
  sc: git
  workspace_type: Application
deploy:
  artifact: build/libs/ApplicationKotlin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

I do have a .ebextensions folder, with a variables.config file
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    SCHEME: http
    HOST: localhost
    LOCALHOST: 127.0.0.1

But when I do eb deploy, I don't think this is being upload. Or if it is, elastic beanstalk is not recognising the environment variables.
Can anyone help?

The eb deploy command works by creating a zip file containing the files from your most recent Git commit. Therefore, to deploy correctly, you need to create a Git commit with the files you want to deploy and then run eb deploy. You can verify which files are being uploaded to your environment by checking the S3 bucket generated by Elastic Beanstalk (EB). The same applies to the eb create command: ensure that files like those in .ebextensions or any other necessary files for your server are included in the Git commit before deploying.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-deploy.html
